# How can I pass URL variable to express.js as in php?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, url, express

Now am converting my php website to express js. There are lot pf script in my front end. All these script generate link like this **page.php?id=10&something=anything**. In express js, I can catch if the url  like this  page.php?/10/anything**. Is there any method to catch variable from url like **page.php?id=10&something=anything** in express js?

Comment: `page/:id/:something` in express router can get you the url variable values .

Comment: why not parsing the URL, spliting "?" as the base split, then go on with "&" split, and also make a failsafe "[]" split of you're ever sending an array of GET variables to your server

Comment: @mithunsatheesh  I have to change all my JavaScript(client side) to make url like that. That is why i asked this question

Comment: @Zlatan , your solution is good. thanks

Comment: @user1263451: i dint get what you mean by client side? .. you can access these data in the controller as `req.params.id` and `req.params.something` and render your view with any thing you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can get using the traditional Express way like "/myroute/id/:number" and also like this "myroute?id=:number"

First: change the route code if your route seems like this:

```
app.get('/user/:id', user.list);
```

to

```
app.get('/user/', user.list);
```

Inside your users.js change the behavior to get the params...

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
    var id = req.query.id;
    console.log("ID: " + id);
};
```

The secret to get the params as you want is "query" in **req.query.id**.